Xでのトレンドを表示する仕組みを知りたい
xのトレンドを表示する仕組みがわかりません。大雑把なフローチャートを日本語で教えてほしいです。それと使っている言語も教えてほしいです。
xはRubyで書かれているらしいのですが、データ分析が得意なpythonなどを使わずにトレンドを表示するのもRubyで行っているのでしょうか。
またデータ分析を行っている言語を使っている理由まで教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

まず、X(旧Twitter)のシステムでメインとなっているプログラミング言語はRubyではありません。初期のTwitterはRuby on Rails(以下、RoR)で書かれていました。これは、RoRの開発速度が非常に高かったため、スタートアップとしては優れていたからです。ただ、当時のRubyはかなり遅く、ユーザー数が大幅に増大してしまったTwitterでは性能不足でした。そこで、2011年頃にRubyをScalaで書き直し、より高速なJVMで動作するようにしました。このように、今のXはRubyとはほぼ無関係です。Rubyについて聞いても意味がありません。
もし、Rubyでのトレンドの仕組みの実装を知りたいのであれば、mastodonのソースコードを調べるのがいいと思います。mastodonはRoRで書かれたTwitterライクなオープンソースのソフトウェアであり、トレンドの仕組みもあるようです。ただ、Xとはアルゴリズムが同じであるとは限りませんので、その点はご注意ください。

回答していただきありがとうございます。Rubyについて調べているとXもRubyを使って作られたというのを勘違いしていました。

Xのヘルプセンターに下記記述があります。

トレンドはアルゴリズムによって決定され、初期設定では、フォローしているアカウント、興味関心、位置情報をもとにカスタマイズされています。ここ数日や今日1日で話題になったトピックではなく、今まさに注目されているトピックが選び出されるため、Twitterで盛り上がっている最新の話題をリアルタイムで見つけることができます。

トレンドはどのように決定されますか？
具体的なロジックは開示されていないのではないでしょうか？
